# Passing an object from one class to another

Tags: ruby

Here's code that **works** but I'm looking to make it as clean as possible, to get the output without having to build a hash.

```
class Person
  attr_accessor :name, :age
  
  def initialize(name, age)
    @name = name
    @age = age
  end
  
  def create
    Report.create({name: @name, age: @age})
  end
end

class Report < Person
  
  def self.create(attributes)
    puts "Hello, this is my report. I am #{attributes[:name]} and my age is #{attributes[:age]}."
  end
end

me = Person.new("Andy", 34)
me.create # Hello, this is my report. I am Andy and my age is 34.
```

Here are my changes that didn't work, but is there a method that would?

```
def create
  Report.create
end
```

and

```
def self.create(attributes)
  puts "Hello, this is my report. I am #{:name} and my age is #{:age}."
end
```

but the output was "I am name and my age is age."

Comment: `class Report < Person` – that inheritance looks odd. Is a `Report` a special kind of `Person`?

Comment: The names aren't important, I was really just playing around with code to see if I could get the it to work.

Comment: @Andy `#{:name}` will **always** evaluate to _name_. The interpolation `#{...}` evaluates the expression which is inside, applies the `to_s` method to it, and uses the resulting string. In your case, the inside expression is `:name`, which is of class `Symbol`. Applying `to_s` to a symbol always returns the string representation of the symbol, i.e. `name` in your example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could just pass the person, something like this:

```
class Person
  attr_accessor :name, :age
  
  def initialize(name, age)
    @name = name
    @age = age
  end
  
  def report
    Report.new(self)
  end
end

class Report
  attr_accessor :person
  
  def initialize(person)
    @person = person
  end

  def to_s
    "Hello, this is my report. I am #{person.name} and my age is #{person.age}."
  end
end

me = Person.new("Andy", 34)
puts me.report
# Hello, this is my report. I am Andy and my age is 34.
```

Note that I've changed some details:

- `Report` doesn't inherit from `Person`
- `Report` instances are created via `new`
- `Person#create` is now `Person#report`
- `Report` uses `to_s` for the output (which is called by `puts`)